# IFrame causing javascript code to not execute

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Does anyone know why this code doesn't work. This means, the alert is NOT fired

```
<iframe/>
<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello');</script>
```

While this code with the alert BEFORE the Iframe works perfeclty. This means the alert is fired

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello');</script>
<iframe/>
```

Seems that no javascript placed after the iframe is executed, I don't find any logic to this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to close the `<iframe>` tag like this:

```
<iframe></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello');</script>
```

Comment: I should add that the reason this is the answer is that <iframe/> is not really a valid tag. They can't be closed in that fashion.

Comment: They can be closed in that fashion, but only in XHTML, and not in HTML-compatible XHTML (i.e. HTML served as text/html so that Internet Explorer will parse it because it doesn't support XHTML)

Comment: I have to wait some minutes in order to be allowed to accept an answer, Stack Overflow rules. Not sure why they did it like this.

Comment: +1 good thing I only spent 10 minutes before searching stack overflow! :)